# Перебор всех бинарных строк string от 0 до заданной размерности

Tags: c#, алгоритм

Например, n = 2, тогда строки:

```
    ""
    "0"
    "1"
    "00"
    "01"
    "10"
    "11"
```

Необходимость в хранении уже просмотренных строк отсутствует. На данный момент генерирую путем добавления '0' и '1' ко всем строкам предыдущей размерности, храня все в List. Работает быстро, но занимает много места, да и List не бесконечен.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

На мой взгляд, самый простой путь - пробегая весь необходимый диапазон чисел от `0` до `1 << n` (что есть `2` в степени `n`), на лету получать строку, используя метод [`Convert.ToString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/14kwkz77(v=vs.110).aspx) с указанием основания системы счисления `2`:

```
int n = 3;
int maxNumber = 1 << n;

for (int i = 0; i < maxNumber; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(i, 2));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int MAX_LENGTH = 10;
for(long i = 0; ; i++)
{
  string s = Convert.ToString(i, 2);
  if (s.Length > MAX_LENGTH)
    break;
  Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```